# Unable to split due to int object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I'm trying to split ('/') from my columns and only take the 1st value of the data on each columns row.But it return an error. Here is the code :

```
df.dropna(axis=0, subset=['rate'], inplace=True)
df.replace('NEW',0,inplace=True)
df.replace('-',0,inplace=True)
df['rate'].unique()
```

cleaning data, return :

> array(['4.1/5', '3.8/5', '3.7/5', '3.6/5', '4.6/5', '4.0/5', '4.2/5',
> '3.9/5', '3.1/5', '3.0/5', '3.2/5', '3.3/5', '2.8/5', '4.4/5',
> '4.3/5', 0, '2.9/5', '3.5/5', '2.6/5', '3.8 /5', '3.4/5', '4.5/5',
> '2.5/5', '2.7/5', '4.7/5', '2.4/5', '2.2/5', '2.3/5', '3.4 /5',
> '3.6 /5', '4.8/5', '3.9 /5', '4.2 /5', '4.0 /5', '4.1 /5',
> '3.7 /5', '3.1 /5', '2.9 /5', '3.3 /5', '2.8 /5', '3.5 /5',
> '2.7 /5', '2.5 /5', '3.2 /5', '2.6 /5', '4.5 /5', '4.3 /5',
> '4.4 /5', '4.9/5', '2.1/5', '2.0/5', '1.8/5', '4.6 /5', '4.9 /5',
> '3.0 /5', '4.8 /5', '2.3 /5', '4.7 /5', '2.4 /5', '2.1 /5',
> '2.2 /5', '2.0 /5', '1.8 /5'], dtype=object)

```
def split(x):
  return x.split('/')[0]
df['rate'].apply(split)

>---------------------------------------------------------------------------
>AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
><ipython-input-149-aee80314807f> in <module>()
>----> 1 df['rate'].apply(split)

>1 frames
>pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

><ipython-input-146-42260b529a6a> in split(x)
>      1 def split(x):
>----> 2   return x.split('/')[0]

>AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: Your function should be working by just tuning `int` to `str` before you split that like: 

`def col_split(x):
     return str(x).split('/')[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

typecasting values will resolve errors.

```py
def split(x):
  return float(str(x).split('/')[0].replace(' ', ''))
df['rate'].apply(split)
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is there is replace by integers, not strings:

```
df.replace('NEW',0,inplace=True)
df.replace('-',0,inplace=True)
```

Need repalce by `'0'` - string `0`:

```
df.replace(['NEW', '-'], '0', inplace=True)

def split(x):
  return x.split('/')[0]
df['rate'].apply(split)
```

Pandas solution:

```
df.replace('NEW',0,inplace=True)
df.replace('-',0,inplace=True)
df['rate'].str.split('/').str[0]
```